# rel=image_src isn't changing the thumbnail

Tags: meta-tags, facebook-sharer

I added this code to the head but when I try to post something about a website inside a Facebook page, the image that I specified is still not showing up as an option.  I'm using wordpress as a CMS. Any ideas why?

```
<meta content="something" name="title">
<meta content="something="og:description">    
<link href="thumbnail.jpeg" rel="image_src">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to pin-point the issue.
Sometimes there is a caching issue and feeding your URL through this tool forces Facebook to scrape your URL again hence refreshing the cached `og:tags`

Further more your `og:tags` should look more like this :

`<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>`
`<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>`

Notice the `property` attribute and not the `content` attribute that you (possibly) used.  The correct syntax is available at this link :  http://ogp.me/